# XPage custom control loading existing values into table

Tags: json, xpages

I have an XPage with a custom control ccxGrid. In this custom control, it calls another XPage that builds a JSON string that in turn populates the table on the main XPage.

My issue is that when the page is refreshed the same documents are added to the table again and again. Is there a way to check if the document is already in the table to not add it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a viewScope variable that you set and then check on every refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer based on my comment above. Use a viewScope variable that you set initially and check on every build of the JSON string:

```
if (!viewScope.alreadyHandled) {
    viewScope.alreadyHandled = true;

    // Do your JSON string processing
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this would of worked but I ended up solving it another way. I was making an instance of a java class in an ssjs call which passed in a session. The way I had it setup was using the same session over and over rather than actually creating a new instance. By moving it, the page actually refreshed the session and no longer used the same session it had retrieved on the first call. Thanks for your help!